# Is it possible to view HTML source auto-formatted in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, formatting, html

I am writing a Web site in PHP, and the HTML it renders is not well formatted and hard to read in Firefox (most of it is on a single line).

I don't want to mess up my PHP code by adding loads of white space formatting stuff, so I was wondering if there is an option or perhaps an add-on to Firefox that will give me the ability to view the source indented according to the HTML's structure.

Comment: Note that recent versions of Firefox (I think it was since 4, confirmed for 10+) come with the ability to do syntax highlighting and word wrapping under the `View` menu of the source window. Just right click => `View Page Source` to open this window.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### View Source Chart 2.7

**[UPDATE]:** original link was broken, here is the website: http://viewsourcechart.com/

Right click -> View source chart

This is what I get for the Google home page HTML source:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Firefox addon is not available as of 2023 and the author's homepage leads to some scammy site. This may have been a very useful answer but as of now it's not and may even be slightly dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

From [here](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/7-firefox-extensions-to-explore-page-source-code/7375/)

[***View Source Chart***](http://jennifermadden.com/scripts/ViewRenderedSource.html)    Graphically displays source structure.

[image]

[***JSView 2.0.5***](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2076)     Displays information on page external files.

[image]

[***HighlightAll***](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4240)     Highlights identical elements in the code.

[image]

[***Html Validator***](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249)   Validates HTML of the current page.

[image]

[***View Formatted Source***](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/697)   Shows source structure.

[image]

[***SourceEditor***](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1760)    Allows to edit code and view the results.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I normally use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for debugging html output.

This allows me to se the html as it's rendered by the browser, together with the well-formatted source in Firebug. I can also inspect elements in the displayed html and see where they come from in the originating html source.

Comment: Who downvoted in 2003 an answer from 2009 ?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is looking for the same functionality in 2019, there is Fire Source Viewer [1] for Firefox Quantum which displays the beautified HTML DOM after javascripts manipulates it, which is even better than having only the html source delivered by the webserver.

[1] https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fire-source-viewer/

Answer (score 1):

No addon is needed, just use FF's "inspect element", you have everything to read the source code.[image]

Answer (score -1):

[Web developer plugin:](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/)

> The Web Developer extension adds various web developer tools to a
>   browser. The extension is available for Chrome and Firefox, and will
>   run on any platform that these browsers support including Windows, OS
>   X and Linux

[image]

Comment: I have this installed but its dosent do what I need
I think i have not been clean enough about what i mean by "formatted"
I will edit the question now

Comment: At least give a brief description as to the salient feature of the plugin that relates to the question. Otherwise, it's just a flippant answer.

Comment: The web developer plugin is a very popular plugin that, among other things, allows one to view source for any page. The source view has some highlighting, so is "formatted"-- although now I see that the OP wants something more specific for the formatting.